# Trigger a Click event in javascript using c#(WebBrowser control)

Tags: c#, javascript, click, webbrowser-control

Is there any way to call the click function from the c# application

Here's the code that set the function:

```
$('#connectbtn').unbind('click').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#connectbtn').bind('click', function() {
               //CODE TO BE EXECUTED
            }).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it,

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "DateTimeFromServer", string.Format(@"<script>  
                                                                                $(function () {{
                                                                                        $('#connectbtn').trigger('click','{0}');
                                                                                    }});
                                                                          </script>", DateTime.Now));
```